# How to find email id or account from which android app is published to play store

Tags: android, google-play

Working on an android app that belongs to an organization. It has been few years, since the app is updated. Now no one knows which account is used to publish the android app. Many employees have changed during this time.

Scenario:

- Have the certificates and all other details to bundle the app.
- The current app is in play store. Email id shown in description is the generic support email id.

Is there any way to find the email id or account used to publish android app (google playstore) ?